# my code is giving me this error can someone help me out

Tags: android

2022-12-25 23:19:31.550 11731-11731/com.example.gonews E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main     Process: com.example.gonews, PID: 11731     android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08015a type #0x12 is not valid

```
package com.example.gonews

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class Newsadaptor(val i:ArrayList<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<newsview>() {
    @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): newsview {
     val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.id.rview,parent,false)
     return newsview(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: newsview, position: Int) {
    val crritem=i[position]
    holder.t.text=crritem
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return i.size
    }
}

class newsview(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
val t:TextView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.t1)
}
```

my android app is not opening but gradle build is happening

Answer (score 0):

In the `onCreateViewHolder()` method you need to inflate the layout you want to show in the recycler view. You are inflating a view instead of a layout, that's why it is giving the exception.

Instead of inflating `R.id.rvview` which I believe is a view or maybe your recycler view, you need to inflate the layout you want to see in the list.

so, you need to replace this line:

```
val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.id.rview,parent,false)
```

to this:

```
val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.your_item_layout,parent,false)
```

Comment: You means  as my recycler view is  foolowing i have to write  LinearView there??